# Can't get bash / apple script to use resize open windows

Tags: bash, applescript

I'm trying to write a bash script to create a new desktop, open 4 programs at once, and then move and resize those programs to go to the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right of my screen (on my Mac).

So far I'm able to get the first 2 parts working, but I can't get the windows to resize properly.

This is what I have tried.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

app1="Zotero"
app2="Google Chrome"
app3="GoodNotes"
app4="Finder"

# Create a new desktop
osascript <<END
tell application "System Events"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
  click button 1 of group "Spaces Bar" of group 1 of group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"
  do shell script quoted form of "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
end tell
END

# Wait for Mission Control to open and switch to the new desktop
sleep 1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down' # Press Control+→ to switch to the new desktop

# Open apps
open -a "$app1"
open -na "$app2" --args --new-window "https://example.com" # Replace with the desired URL for app2
open -a "$app3"
open -a "$app4" ~/Desktop

# Wait for a short time to ensure that the applications have started
sleep 2

# Get the process IDs of the applications
app1_pid=$(pgrep -i "$app1")
app2_pid=$(pgrep -i "$app2")
app3_pid=$(pgrep -i "$app3")
app4_pid=$(pgrep -i "$app4")

# Get the screen dimensions
screen_width=$(system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/ {print $2}')
screen_height=$(system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/ {print $4}')

# Calculate the width and height for each quarter
quarter_width=$((screen_width / 2))
quarter_height=$((screen_height / 2))

# Set the positions and sizes of the applications
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set position of window 1 of process $app1_pid to {0, 22}"              # Top-left
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set size of window 1 of process $app1_pid to {$quarter_width, $quarter_height}" # Resize to quarter size

osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set position of window 1 of process $app2_pid to {$quarter_width, 22}" # Top-right
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set size of window 1 of process $app2_pid to {$quarter_width, $quarter_height}" # Resize to quarter size

osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set position of window 1 of process $app3_pid to {0, $quarter_height}" # Bottom-left
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set size of window 1 of process $app3_pid to {$quarter_width, $quarter_height}" # Resize to quarter size

osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set position of window 1 of process $app4_pid to {$quarter_width, $quarter_height}" # Bottom-right
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set size of window 1 of process $app4_pid to {$quarter_width, $quarter_height}" # Resize to quarter size
```

Can someone help me fix the latter part of this script?

Comment: I'm not fluent in Apple Script, but did you check that your variables have sensible values?  I would turn on tracing with `set -x` just before the resizing statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
osascript << EOF
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay .5
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        set frontWindow to the front window
        if exists frontWindow then
            set position of frontWindow to {0, 0}
            set size     of frontWindow to {1000, 500}
        end if
    end tell
end tell
EOF
```